# Representing an unordered set of vectors as a single vector for neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on a sequence-to-sequence task.  My input values at each time set consist of an **unordered set** of small zero/one vectors.  For instance, at time step *t* my input could be {[0,1,0,1], [1,0,0,1]}, and that would be equivalent to {[1,0,0,1], [0,1,0,1]}, but not to {[0,1,0,1], [0,0,1,1]}.  How should I represent these inputs so that it learns to generalize beyond ordering?

EDIT: I initially asked about one-hot vectors, but realized that a) my application actually requires sets of **dense** 0/1 vectors, and b) as Tom pointed out, one-hots are not so interesting because they could be summed together.  Sorry about the change!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a BiLSTm with shared weights on the two ways the sequence can be ordered as an encoder kind of step.

Comment: Sorry, I edited - they're actually not one-hots, they're dense 0/1 vectors.  I think you're right, it would be trivial to sum if they were one-hots!

Comment: That's what i thought, so I actually deleted it before your comment, What do you think about the bi lstm though?

Comment: Would that work something like as follows: I fix a maximum number of vectors, concatenate them together in an arbitrary order as if they're separate dimensions, but then tie together the weights coming out of them in the input and first hidden layers?

Answer (score 0):

So far this is the solution I found: use all the possible orderings of your input set and the same label so that the model fits all possible combinations of the input vectors inside the set and not an arbitrary order.